# rails actionMailer failing on apparently missing From address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, postfix-mta

An application using postfix for sendmail only was reconfigured to:

```
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

from an inital `all` value. postfix was restarted and then mails stopped being delivered from the application, whereas test mail from the system would be.

The mailer does not use default from values, as different domains are being serviced.

The mailer action thus specifies:

```
if @event.user.email_admin.nil?
  mail(from: "confirm@stourism.events", to: @event.user.email, bcc: "confirm@stourism.events,jr@iwgo.com", subject: t('event_mailer.subject') )
else
  mail(from: "confirm@stourism.events", to: @event.user.email, cc: @event.user.email_admin, bcc: "confirm@stourism.events,jr@iwgo.com", subject: t('event_mailer.subject') )
end
```

the log states

```
EventMailer#contact: processed outbound mail in 2664.5ms I, [2018-09-02T13:53:14.215007 #4797]  
INFO -- : Sent mail to user@some.ws (7.3ms) D, [2018-09-02T13:53:14.215081 #4797] 
DEBUG -- : Date: Sun, 02 Sep 2018 13:53:14 +0200 
To: user@some.ws 
Cc: confirm@stourism.events

[...]

ArgumentError (SMTP From address may not be blank: nil):   app/controllers/events_controller.rb:94:in `package'
```

That particular controller method referred to states:

```
EventMailer.contact(@event.id).deliver_now
```

production.rb defines

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'stourism.events' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

Where did this become wrong after the postfix change?

Comment: Solution:  ensure BOTH postfix and application (when in production) are restarted.